# Install laravel.phar in Linux Mint 16

Tags: php, curl, laravel

I just downloaded `laravel.phar` and copied it to /bin with the proper permissions but upon running `laravel.phar new test` I get the error

```
Crafting application...

[Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException]               
The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.
```

I already have curl installed after previously running `sudo apt-get install curl`. Am I still missing something?

EDIT: I installed lamp using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` in case you needed to know.

Comment: A standalone cURL that you installed is different from the cURL php extension, see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the cURL extension with:
`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable your curl extension. You can enable this from your `php.ini` file. You have to uncomment it by removing the `;` before the `extension=php_curl.dll` inside that ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the article will be useful to install laravel using laravel.phar file.

[kvcodes](http://kvcodes.com/2014/04/install-laravel-using-laravel-phar-file/)